UI Button is not working

I have a problem on the canvas. When I remove the camera  in the FPS Controller player and UnChecked the FPS Controller it works but when the Camera is inside the the FPS Controller I can't click anything.

Can you edit your question to show us how you've configured your canvas and event system objects?
